# Bootstrap well filling row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a row and three columns with equal height within it, like this:

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 panel">
            <div class="well">
                <strong class="text-info">well 1</strong>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 panel">
            <div class="well">
                <strong class="text-info">well 2</strong>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 panel">
            <div class="well">
                <strong class="text-info">well 3</strong>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I want to achieve is having three wells with the same size (size of the biggest one). I tried adding `.well` to column class, but this solution leaks spaces between wells.

Answer (score 0):

Try using class text-justify

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 panel">
        <div class="well text-justify">
            <strong class="text-info">well 1</strong>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 panel">
        <div class="well  text-justify">
            <strong class="text-info">well 2</strong>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 panel">
        <div class="well  text-justify">
            <strong class="text-info">well 3</strong>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It has no effect besides alligning text to the left.